# How to read key value in a grouped IEnumerable list?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

How to access/read the key value in the resultListGrouped below?

```
IEnumerable resultList = from...select...ToList();

var resultListGrouped = ResultList.GroupBy(t => t.Code).ToList();

// how to read the key value? 
foreach ( ????)
{

}
```

Comment: What did you try, and how did it fail to solve your problem?

Comment: Why don't you insert a select after the Group by? Or just use Distinct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `Key` property of the group:

```
foreach (var group in resultListGrouped)
{
    var code = group.Key;
}
```

Side-note: it's not necessary to append everywhere `ToList`. Note that it's creating a new list in a loop. If you want to do further actions with a query and you don't need that list it's more efficient to use `ToList` only at the end. If you only need it in the `foreach` you don't need `ToList` at all.